# Connect to PgAdmin III via localhost

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I just want to login for first time, from pgAdmin III via `localhost` on openSuSE 13.1 64x.
My `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

```
postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mydb      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: openSuSE 13.1 64x

Answer (score 6):

The basic misunderstanding: **"localhost" is not a local connection.** Your "trust" line in `pg_hba.conf` is not applicable for your connection:

```
local   all   all   trust
```

That only applies for connections via **Unix-domain socket**. Best choice for you is to connect via this route. [Per pgAdmin documentation:](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html)

> The host is the IP address of the machine to contact, or the fully
>   qualified domain name. On Unix based systems, **the address field may be
>   left blank to use the default PostgreSQL Unix Domain Socket on the
>   local machine**, or be set to an alternate path containing a PostgreSQL
>   socket. If a path is entered, it must begin with a “/”. The port
>   number may also be specified.

Bold emphasis mine.

More about connecting without password in this related answer on SO:
[Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

Comment: Dead first link, I would suggest to replace it with; https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/connecting.html or https://documentation.help/pgAdmin3/connect.html

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that you want to connect via TCP to localhost.

(for local socket connection see Erwin's answer)

Two options to ease your pain:

1. in pg_hba.conf, in the lines with localhost IP, replace "ident" by "md5" and restart - then you will be able to use password logins
2. if (1) is not acceptable, sudo to "postgres" user and create another superuser login - then use this login to connect from PgAdmin.

   > ```
   >  sudo su - postgres
   >  psql -c "create user myloginname superuser password 'mypa55w0rd' "
   > ```
3. [LEARN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html) how this stuff really works and adjust pg_hba.conf to your real needs.